# Finding the rank of matrix $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

supose $A$ is a $4\times4$ matrix such that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=4$. Find the rank of the matrix $A^2$.
if there is a major rule for the power $k$ and not specially the power $2$.

Comment: A $4\times 4$ matrix with rank $4$ is very special; it is a ___ matrix! Hence $A^k$ is also ___, and hence has rank $4$. (This wouldn't work for a $4\times 4$ matrix of some other rank...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $rank(A) = 4$ for $4 \times 4$ matrix, then it is invertible. therefore $A^2$ is invertible and has rank $4$ too.

Answer (score 2):

Just notice that $$\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2\neq 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for a $4\times 4$ matrix with $\operatorname{rank}(A)=4$ you have a one-to-one and onto function $$\widetilde{A}: K^{4\times 1}\rightarrow K^{4\times 1}, x\mapsto A\cdot x$$.

For $A^2$ you simply get $\widetilde{A}\circ\widetilde{A}$ which also is a one-to-one and onto function.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sylvester's formula:
rank(A)+rank(B)-n≦rank(AB)≦min[rank(A),rank(B)]
where A and B are of orders m×n and n×p respectively.
Setting A=B here with n=4,
4≦rank(A^2)≦4.